# How to manage access to a database object properly?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I am wondering weather there is a better solution to my problem. 
Better in the sense that not every object of the class Segment has to create a new database object.

I am trying to keep only one database in my program because the database is very big and I am sure there is a more efficient solution to this.

The Database holds objects of the class SegmentInformetion in a List. Each Object contains many informations each Segment object needs for its instantiation.

The Layer Class contains a List of Segments. The Layers Constructor contains an array with IDs. Every Segment will get its Information from the Database depending on the ID with which it is calling the Database.

```
Database {
    List<SegmentInformation> segInfoList;

    public SegmentInformation getSegInfos( int id ){
        return segInfoList.get(id);
    }
}

Layer{
    List<Segments> segmentList; 

    public Layer( int[] segmentIDs ){ 
        for (int i : segmentIDs){
            segmentList.add( new Segment( segmentIDs[i] ) );
        }
    }
}

Segment{
    double value1;
    //....
    double valuenN;

    public Segment(int sID){
        Database db = new Database();
        SegmentInformation info = db.getSegInfos( sID );
        value1 = info.getValue1();
        //....
        valueN = info.getValueN();
    }
}
```

I am trying to avoid a global static variable which contains the Database.
Any suggestions for a more suitable way to instantiate all the Segment objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Singleton to contain all the Segment objects:

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a software design
>   pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single"
>   instance. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to
>   coordinate actions across the system. The term comes from the
>   mathematical concept of a singleton.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Thank you Andres for your help. I will need many Segment objects which will behave differently. Do I use the Singelton to contain the Database instead? And is there in theory another approach than the Singelton pattern (which I am trying to avoid) ?

Comment: @jasmindragon if you want a single instance of the data, Singleton is the way to go. If you implement your app using Spring framework, you'll get the Singleton pattern out of the box and you won't have to implement it yourself.